# Como inserir nova imagem em projeto com COMPASS

Tags: css3, front-end, sass, compass

Tenho as imagens que utilizo em meu projeto e desejo adicionar uma nova imagem para utilizar no site, porém não consigo fazer com que a imagem seja adicionada aos sprites gerados pelo COMPASS

Comment: Caçando assunto acabei de conseguir fazer... 
1 - Na pasta ICONS adicione a imagem que deseja adicionar ao projeto;
2 - Na pasta images (antes de ICONS) exclua o sprite gerado pelo COMPASS para seu projeto;
3 - Recompile os arquivos que a imagem sera automaticamente gerada no local correto

Pronto, basta utilizar a imagem adicionada

Answer (score 1):

Para fazer sprite com compass precisamos isolar as imagens que desejamos juntar em uma pasta, que se chamará sprite e ficará dentro da pasta imagens.
Precisamos avisar o Compass que sempre que houver um arquivo .png na pasta, ele precisa ser atualizado. Para isso, iremos ao seu principal.scss e acrescentaremos uma linha que diga isso:

```
@import 'sprite/*.png'
```

Veja que apos salvar o terminal vai responder

```
create imagens/sprite-s1e1f3a7a9e.png
```

Ele comunica que o Compass criou um sprite com aquele nome
E após fazer e desfazer com essa  pequena alteração no seu principal.scss, apenas para que o Compass detecte uma alteração e compile novamente, voce pode verificar o resultado na pasta imagens.